# CompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies -- Add reference to System.Web.UI.WebControls

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, assemblies

I am compiling classes at run-time using the `CodeDomProvider` class. This works fine for classes only using the `System` namespace:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public String HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

If I try to compile a class using `System.Web.UI.WebControls` though, I get this error:

> {error CS0006: Metadata file 'System.Web.UI.WebControls' could not be found}
>   System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerError

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
var cp = new CompilerParameters();

cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Web.UI.WebControls");
```

How do I reference the `System.Web.UI.WebControls` namespace?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You reference assemblies, not namespaces. You should use MSDN to look up the name of the assembly that contains the classes you need to use: in this case it's going to be:

```
var cp = new CompilerParameters();
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Web.dll");
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Do you think I should supply the full path to the assembly? If yes; how might I do that dynamically?

Comment: Ah, System.Web.UI.WebControls.dll doesn't exist -- the classes in that namespace live in System.Web.dll instead.

Answer (score 44):

You can loop through all the currently loaded assemblies:

```
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                            .GetAssemblies()
                            .Where(a => !a.IsDynamic)
                            .Select(a => a.Location);   

cp.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(assemblies.ToArray());
```

Comment: Why catch try/catch when .Where(a => !a.IsDynamic ) would do it?

Comment: My original answer worked with .net 2.0 which is what I was using at the time I wrote the code. Neither LINQ nor the Assembly.IsDynamic property exist in .net 2.0.

Comment: Note that it's AddRange not Add (would fix but can't make <6 char edit).

Answer (score 6):

This proved to be a little less brute force in my case. I was building an addin and there were 730 assemblies loaded in the current domain so there was major lag involved.

```
var assemblies = someType.Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies().ToList();
   var assemblyLocations =  
assemblies.Select(a => 
     Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(a.FullName).Location).ToList();

assemblyLocations.Add(someType.Assembly.Location);

cp.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(assemblyLocations.ToArray());
```

Comment: +1. I used your proposal and worked great. Just you need to edit the last line and write `cp.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(assemblyLocations.ToArray());` instead.