# Can't include Newtonsoft JSON in CSharpCodeProvider script

Tags: c#, json.net, csharpcodeprovider

I am trying to use JSON in a dynamically compiled script. However, when I include the library and add a JObject, I get errors like: "The type 'System.Dynamic.IDynamicMetaObjectProvider' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'."

I included MathNet.Numerics just fine.

**Here is my setup.**

- Console application .NET Framework 4 (so it matches the runtime
  compile)
- Nuget install MathNet.Numerics
- Nuget install Newtonsoft
- Point the runtime compile to the debug folder with the dlls.

**Test Code**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.Reflection;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{

  public class RunScript0
  {


    public bool Compile()
    {

      //Add using statements here
      string source = "namespace UserScript\r\n{\r\nusing System;\r\n" +
                "using System.IO;\r\n" +
                "using System.Collections.Generic;\r\n" +
                "using MathNet.Numerics.Distributions;\r\n" +
                "using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;\r\n" +
                "using Newtonsoft.Json;\r\n" +
                "public class RunScript\r\n{\r\n" +
                "private const int x = 99;\r\n" +
                "public int Eval()\r\n{\r\n" +
                //Remove following line and all works fine
                "JObject j = new JObject();\r\n" +
                "return x; \r\n\r\n}\r\n}\r\n}";

      Dictionary<string, string> provOptions =
        new Dictionary<string, string>();

      provOptions.Add("CompilerVersion", "v4.0");
      CodeDomProvider compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider(provOptions);


      CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
      string appPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
      parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(appPath + "\\MathNet.Numerics.dll");
      parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(appPath + "\\Newtonsoft.Json.dll");
      //Tried adding but didn't help parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(appPath + "\\System.Core.dll");

      parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
      var results = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, source);
      // Check for compile errors / warnings
      if (results.Errors.HasErrors || results.Errors.HasWarnings)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(results.Errors.Count.ToString() + " Erorrs");
        for (int i = 0; i < results.Errors.Count; i++)
          Console.WriteLine(results.Errors[i].ToString());
        return false;
      }
      else
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Compiled Successfully");
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      RunScript0 A = new RunScript0();
      A.Compile();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What .NET version do you use to compile?

Comment: I believe it is 4.0 as shown in the code - provOptions.Add("CompilerVersion", "v4.0"); or were you meaning something else?

Comment: My question is for the .Net version of all code (not the meta code).

Comment: Project Target Framwork = .Net Framework 4.   I selected this one ato match the meta compile "v4.0", this way any dlls in the exe directory would be the right versions and could be referenced in the meta code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add a reference to **System** and **System.Core** from the GAC (Global Assembly Cache) :

```cs
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
```

I think it's dependances from **Newtonsoft.Json**.

Comment: It doesn't list those in the dependencies in Nuget.

Comment: Strange, your suggestion worked on my test application, but in my real one I get other errors. I copied the exact same code and dlls under a test function and the first error I get is  - The type 'System.Dynamic.IDynamicMetaObjectProvider' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.  If I add the dotstandard.dll like the system.dll then I get a ton of "defined in multiple assemblies"

Comment: Maybe this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1020547/2703673

Comment: Thanks I wish I would have seen this before. The loop and addRange example in there was perfect.